# How are Open Graph og:see_also tags intended to behave in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've implemented `og:see_also` into my posts, but when they're liked, no additional webpages appear.

Is there specific criteria that needs to be met (i.e. do they require a specific og:type)?
Must they be placed in a specific place within the Open Graph Meta Tag order?

Here's how they're set up:

```
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://mywebsite.com/article1/">
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://mywebsite.com/article2/">
```

They're displayed appropriately in the FB Debugger Tool. I'm just wondering if perhaps I may be doing something wrong, or if the see_also articles will only appear intermittently?

Here's the full code:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://THEWEBPAGE.COM">
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://IMAGE-HERE.com">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://IMAGE-HERE.com">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300">

<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION">
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://mywebsite.com/article1/">
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://mywebsite.com/article2/">
```

Answer (score 3):

[The official OpenGraph protocol page doesn't mention anything about `og:see_also`,](http://ogp.me/#type_article) and [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) doesn't do anything with it.

However, [Pinterest mentions it](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_article/), which suggests it may one of the `og:` tags Pinterest has extended from the standard. The only description we get is:

> URL pointing to other related articles from the same domain. Up to 6 og:see_also tags can be provided.

Presumably, this tag would only have an effect when Pinterest users "pin" your page and get a "Rich Pin" out of it, which is a feature you'd have to [apply for](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/validator/).

Comment: It is in the website open graph documentation though:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/

Comment: @FredStark good catch — it wasn’t at the time I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in Facebook's debugger.

Some websites will show this tag but I think it is coming from the schema `sameAs` tag.

https://schema.org/